# Change/modify branch that I want to merge from in GitHub pull request

Tags: github, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I erroneously committed local changes on the "production" branch my organization uses for a project and opened a pull request to merge those changes (one simple commit) into the "development" branch (which is where changes should go in the period of time while they are not consolidated into a release).

Obviously, the "production" branch is hundreds of commits behind the "development" one. Is there a way I can change the pull request to be merging changes from another branch (the appropriate one, branching from "development") or my options are just to pull changes from "development" into my local branch involved in the PR or close the PR and open a new one?

Comment: PRs are a GitHub thing, not a Git thing. You *can* rewrite a PR (using `git push --force`) but it's so easy to close a bad one and open a new one, and so confusing to come across a completely-rewritten PR, that there's no reason to be fancy here. Just close the bad PR and open a good one.

Comment: You can create a new branch, pull the changes, and use [git cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to only transfer the single commit to it, then just open a new pull request.